# in maple how to find the asymptotic curve of $\frac{x}{lnx}$

Tags: maple

In maple how can i find the asymptotic curve of $\frac{x}{lnx}$

I'd appreciate if one can tell me what's the output as well.

thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to graph $y=\frac{x}{\ln x}$?

Comment: im trying to find it's asymptotic curve.

Comment: Looking up "asymptotic curve," it seems these things are defined for *surfaces* and you have not provided a surface. Perhaps you are looking for a curve that looks asymptotically like that of $x/\ln x$, similar to *asymptotes* in elementary math. What exactly are you looking for, then? You won't get a function any more basic than $x/\ln x$ itself that has sufficiently similar-looking curve.

Comment: for example: the asymptotic curve of $f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}$ is the line $y=x$

Comment: Okay. An asymptotic curve of $\frac{x}{\ln x}$ is ... $\frac{x}{\ln x}$. Like I said, you will not find any function more basic than this with a sufficiently similar looking curve.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is properly called an "asymptotic series" rather than an "asymptotic curve". The Maple command is `asympt(x/ln(x), x)`, but Maple's response is simply $x/ln(x)$, like @anon said.